# Does `MatchIt::matchit()` not support exlusion of variables in formula?

Tags: r, regression, propensity-score-matching

My goal is to exclude `net_tfa` from the formula. Nervertheless, I would like to use this variable in subsequent steps. Why does `matchit()` not except variable exclusion by `-variable`? How can I overcome this?

A comparison with `lm()`:

```r
# toy data
# install.packages("hdm")
library(hdm); data("pension")

# allowing convergence
pension <- pension[, c("p401", "net_tfa", "age", "db", 
                       "educ","fsize", "hown", "inc", 
                       "male", "marr","pira", "twoearn")]

lm(p401 ~ . -net_tfa,
   data = pension)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = p401 ~ . - net_tfa, data = pension)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)          age           db         educ        fsize         hown  
#>   9.865e-02   -1.718e-03    1.174e-01    3.975e-04   -3.112e-03    6.556e-02  
#>         inc         male         marr         pira      twoearn  
#>   3.967e-06   -1.347e-02   -1.027e-02    6.407e-02    2.519e-02

# install.packages("MatchIt")
library(MatchIt)
matchit(formula = p401 ~ . -net_tfa,
        data = pension,
        method = "nearest",
        link = "probit",
        estimand = "ATT",
        replace = TRUE)
#> A matchit object
#>  - method: 1:1 nearest neighbor matching with replacement
#>  - distance: Propensity score
#>              - estimated with probit regression
#>  - number of obs.: 9915 (original), 4435 (matched)
#>  - target estimand: ATT
#>  - covariates: net_tfa, age, db, educ, fsize, hown, inc, male, marr, pira, twoearn
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see, `net_tfa` is covariate in the latter case.

---

In case I missed tags, please edit.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe: `formula = p401 ~ ., data = subset(pension, select=-net_tfa),`

Comment: Clearly, subsetting the data set is an option. I thought about that. But I don't want to change the data. My goal is to get it work with the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't include the variable in the main formula, it will still appear in the matched dataset produced by `match.data()`, which is just a copy of your original dataset with unmatched observations dropped and additional columns added. It won't appear in the `summary()` output, but you can always request it using the `addlvariables` argument. So just include the variables you want to match on in the main formula.

If you are using the formula to estimate a propensity score, then using `-var` does exclude var from the propensity score model since the formula is passed directly to the model fitting function (by default, `glm()`). But the variable will still show up in the balance output because that relies on `model.frame()`, which includes all variables in the formula even if removed using `-`. The `print()` method for `matchit` objects prints the variables that will appear in the balance summary.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This means exclusion by formula specification with `-var` is not possible?

Comment: Ah! This is enlightening, thank you very much! Please move your comment to the answer if you don't mind. Thank you!